# Execution failed for task :app:testDebugUnitTest in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Suddenly build failed in my project and try to run assemble from `gradle` option **Android studio** below error log showinng

```
TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:207)
       .....
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:417)
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Which version Android studio you used?

Comment: facing the same issue with Android Bumblebee latest config

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if you gradle.properties is proper configured and if the line of jvm arguments is not commented.

[gradle.properties image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR4wP.png)

When this line is commented or when the parameter `-Xmx2048m` is with a low value, you will have out of JVM memory error that is the root cause of `app:testDebugUnitTest` failure.